# Dealing with a footer line in csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My input file comes in with a line at the bottom that looks like this:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I'm taking the entries and putting them in dictionaries, so I always have one line that is all screwed up.  I am using the `reader.next()` method for my header, is there something similar that I can do with this footer record?

Comment: What is the exact error you get when parsing this line? An exception?

Comment: loop through line by line and test data for validity? I'm not sure there's any better answer than that other than modifying the input file (regex maybe).

Comment: `reader.next()` - what is `reader` ? which modules/libraries are you using ? how does your code & input look like ? if I had to guess I'd say that your file contains spaces that are being considered as commas, you can either sanitize your file before you start reading it, or make sure to read only comma separated values (depending on the package you're using - most of them are configurable and you can set up the delimiter you want to use).

Comment: It's not an exception or an error, it just includes an entry in my dictionary that looks odd.  I feed my processed file into HP Exstream, and I'm pretty sure I'll get an error when it tries to process this line.  @alfasin I'm using the csv module, and reader is just what I'm calling my reader object.

Comment: You might be able to use something like the `iter_except()` recipe (in [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=iter_except#recipes) section of the docs) to call `reader.next` and check what it returned.

Answer (score 1):

if you import your csv via [pandas read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you can have pandas automatically skip the footer line...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
datastr=pd.read_csv('datafile',delimiter=',',header=[0,1,2],skipfooter=1)
datastr=datastr.as_matrix()
```

this will use rows 0,1,2 as headerlines an skip the last row of the file...

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if this would conflict with my use of other modules, but seems very clean!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the last element in an iterator without traversing all the elements or calculate the length of iterator.

In this case you can use `itertools.tee` to create a copy of your reader object and then `next` it one time more than the main reader object till the new iterator fall one item in front of the main reader and then you can call the `next` function on it, in a `try-except` statement each time you iterate over your main reader object. and when it raised a `StopIteration` error you stop the iteration over the main reader object.

example :

```
import csv
from itertools import tee
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     next_reader,spamreader=tee(spamreader)
     next(next_reader)
     try :
        for row in spamreader:
            print ', '.join(row)
            next(next_reader)
     except StopIteration:
          pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, [])  # Skip header.
    last_row = next(reader, [])  # Fetch the first row.
    for new_row in reader:
        process(last_row)
        last_row = new_row

    # At this point `last_row` is the last row,
    # and has not been processed.
```